# Modify routes in existing Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I try to modify existing routes in rails application to make it more readable for human and for google.

Existing route example: `http://localhost:3000/search_adv?locale=de&q[home_type_eq]=1`

To: `http://localhost:3000/bowling?locale=de`
How to create these routes without 'big' code modifying?

Where home_type=1 parameter corresponds to bowling.
      home_type=2 to restaurant and so on. 
Altogether six such parameters.

In routes.rb:  `get 'search_adv' => 'pages#search_adv'`
In controller:

```
  def search_adv
    if params[:search_adv].present? && params[:search_adv].strip != ""
      session[:loc_search] = params[:search_adv]
    end

    if session[:loc_search] && session[:loc_search] != ""
      @rooms_address = Room.where(active: true).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).near(session[:loc_search], 1000, order: 'distance')
    else
      @rooms_address = Room.where(active: true).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    end
```

Comment: I would suggest that you start by reading [the rails documentation on default route parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults). It appears you'd like to define six custom routes, with a specified default query parameter.

Comment: If you can't figure it out from the documentation, then perhaps share what you've tried -- maybe there's a way we could improve the documentation to make this task clearer for future developers such as yourself?

Comment: You should include both the `html.erb` file that created the page they are coming from, and the actual pertinent html of the page generated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question shows how you are thinking about rails which is not the correct way and I would also suggest what Tom Lord suggested but there is a way to do what you want to do, although it would require major refactoring of your code base and not worth it:

You can add a M, V and C each for the home_types (restaurant, bowling etc.) and then redirect from `search_adv` method to that controller route based on params.

For example:

You hit `http://localhost:3000/search_adv?locale=de&q[home_type_eq]=1` and then in `search_adv` you can

```
  if params[the exact params containing your value] == 1
    redirect_to bowlings_path(locale: 'de')
  end
```

The user will not feel it as the redirection will happen on the back-end but the route later will look like:

```
  http://localhost:3000/bowlings?locale=de
```